# In Spring, Are command object stored in session or in request

Tags: session, spring-mvc, command-objects

command objects are stored in session or comes along with the page request?

if stored in session, it could cause issue while working on same page in multiple tabs, isn't it?

or do we have control over that?

Thanks
senthil

Answer (score 0):

It is stored in request - as request attributes.

Comment: thanx.. but is there a way to controls its scope?